# How i can change the background-color when my Angular Material Tab is active without using ::ng-deep and viewEncapsulation.none?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I'm trying to change the `background-color` when my [Material Angular Tab](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api) is active.
I check in html inspect and i finded the class:

```
.mat-tab-label-active
```

But my `background-color` property only work when i use `::ng-deep`. I'm trying to avoid it because can be depreciated some day.

is working with `::ng-deep:`

```
::ng-deep .mat-tab-label-active {
    background-color: #0b7f66!important;
    opacity: 1!important;
    color: white;
}
```

I tried some things:
encapsule my component in a div with a class:

```
<div class="testing-encapsulation">
  <mat-tab-group animationDuration='0' mat-stretch-tabs class="mt-3">
      ...
```

And in my component scss:

```
.testing-encapsulation {
  .mat-tab-label-active {
      background-color: #0b7f66!important;
      opacity: 1!important;
      color: white;
    }
}
```

Didn't work too.

There's a way to do this without set `ViewEncapsulation.none()` and `::ng-deep`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this in style.css to make all material tabs

```
.mat-tab-label-active {
      background-color: #0b7f66 !important;
      opacity: 1!important;
      color: white;
    }
```

for spesific tab

```
  <mat-tab-group class="testing-encapsulation" animationDuration='0' mat-stretch-tabs class="mt-3">
```

in style.css

```
.testing-encapsulation {
  .mat-tab-label-active {
      background-color: #0b7f66 !important;
      opacity: 1!important;
      color: white;
    }
}
```

Comment: in styles.scss i don't need to use !important but i still have to use ::ng-deep

Comment: No you don't need to write  ::ng-deep in style.css

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tabs-material-4wbdrx example demo

Comment: You should use with !important. If you don't use this it notice after click somewhere

Comment: You can increase the specificity of your selector using something like `.test .mat-tab-label.mat-ripple.mat-tab-label-active.ng-star-inserted` to define your styles. Then you can drop the `!important` thing.

Comment: Is there any solution which does not use ::ng-deep and requires you to change only in the component styles ??